# eosjs, have getActions working both ways

Tags: nodeos, transactions, eosjs

I've been struggling with that for a couple days and I'm crawling out for help now ;-)
I've been using eosjs to parse the Actions of an account but all I can see are the transactions created by the account, not the one it received.
How can I get the `eos.getActions("accountname", pos, offset)` to work on incoming transactions as well?

```
const Eos = require('eosjs');

// Connect to a testnet or mainnet
const chain = {
    main: 'aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906', // main network
    jungle: '038f4b0fc8ff18a4f0842a8f0564611f6e96e8535901dd45e43ac8691a1c4dca', // jungle testnet
    sys: 'cf057bbfb72640471fd910bcb67639c22df9f92470936cddc1ade0e2f2e7dc4f' // local developer
};

const config = {
    expireInSeconds: 60,
    broadcast: true,
    verbose: false,
    sign: true,
    debug: false,
    httpEndpoint: 'https://api.eosnewyork.io',
    chainId: chain.main,
    //keyProvider: ['PrivateKeys...'], // WIF string or array of keys.. 
};

//const eos = Eos(config);
const eos = Eos(config);

eos.getActions("newdexpocket", 100000, 100).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`eos.getActions()` is actually a wrapper of `/history/get_actions` RPC API which is provided by the `history_api_plugin` of `nodeos`. For this API endpoint, `account_name` is the name of the account who signed and sent/was sent to this transaction. **However, the majority of public eosio full nodes do not provide this data as it will cost huge amount of their RAM and other computing resources.**

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_actions-1

While I was doing experiments, `https://eosbp.atticlab.net` is one of the rare BP API endpoints who provided this data. Full nodes need to set `filter-on` in `config.ini` in order to retain and provide this data. Nowadays very few BPs do so.

In your case, you are recommended to utilize mongodb for query purposes. You can checkout the `mongo_db_plugin` for nodeos. (https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/mongo_db_plugin)

With `mongo_db_plugin`, you can save all the action data into your mongodb instance and query anyway you like in mongodb. E.g. actions are saved in the `action_traces` mongo collection.

```
db.action_traces.find({'act.account': 'newdexpocket', 'act.authorization.actor': 'newdexpocket'})
```

For better query performance, please add index for 'act.account' and 'act.authorization.actor'.

```
db.action_traces.createIndexes([{'act.authorization.actor': 1}, {'act.account': 1}], {background: true})
```

Btw, `history_api_plugin` is deprecated since eosio v1.2.0 and may be removed in the future. You should consider starting your migration before it's too late.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your answer it's super helpful. Can you ELI5 how to use the mango_db_plugin? I'm not sure I'm following that bit.The documentation does speak about using Mongo and I'm a bit familliar with it but how do I connect the mongo db with eos? Are there public mongo collections on BP endpoints or should I run a local node? Where's the connection point here? I've read the doc but something is missing or I don't understand the full logic, I get it that the plugin is an eosio plugin but how do I use that with NODEJs for example? Thanks in advance for your help ;-)

Comment: Hi @Linda! You will need to have a full node of eos and set it up with mongo_db_plugin. It's currently not a super easy task to get done. You can check this repo out: https://github.com/EOS-BP-Developers/eosio-mongodb-queries

Comment: @Linda And for setting up nodeos, please follow these documentations: 1. Get the eosio code: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/getting-the-code ; 2. Build eosio: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/autobuild-script ; 3. Set it up as non-producing node: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/configuration-file https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/environment-non-producing-node

Comment: @Linda And please remember, the mongodb instance may take over 400GB of disk space if you enable only action_traces collection, or over 1TB if you enable all collections. The syncing process may take days to catch up, or you can download the full data snapshot of the blockchain from https://eosnode.tools/blocks and replay.

Comment: @Linda In the meantime, you can try the API provided by atticlab https://eosbp.atticlab.net . It has the actions data.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the feedback, I'm setting up my own node but not sure about the mongo_db_plugin. I've added the plugin in my config.ini (used to launch my nodeos instance). I can see on getInfo that the node is syncing pretty well but when I connect to mongo I can't see any new database in there... Am I missing anything here? Thanks again for your input,

Comment: Ok, my bad... for future readers the solution is to specify the mongo URI otherwise the plugin is disabled so you just add something like that in the term when launching the nodeos script => `--mongodb-uri mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/EOS`